# C++ SFINAE for array/vector

Tags: c++, sfinae

I want to make an overloaded operator << which is only used by containers (array/vector).

I have the following template:

```
namespace reachability {
    template <typename Container>
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const is_container<Container>(&container)) {
        string result = "{";

        for (values_t elem : container) {
            result += std::string(elem) + ",";
        }

        std::operator<<(out, result.substr(0, result.length() - 1) + "}");
        return out;
    }

    struct values_t {
        string type;
        operator std::string() const { return type; }
    };


    template<typename T, typename _ = void>
    struct is_container : std::false_type {};

    template<typename... Ts>
    struct is_container_helper {};

    template<typename T>
    struct is_container<
        T,
        std::conditional_t<
        false,
        is_container_helper<
        typename T::value_type,
        typename T::size_type,
        typename T::allocator_type,
        typename T::iterator,
        typename T::const_iterator,
        decltype(std::declval<T>().size()),
        decltype(std::declval<T>().begin()),
        decltype(std::declval<T>().end()),
        decltype(std::declval<T>().cbegin()),
        decltype(std::declval<T>().cend())
        >,
        void
        >
    > : public std::true_type{};

}
```

And it's used in:

```
reachability::values_t vals[5];

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    vals[0].type = "zoo";
    vals[1].type = "foo";
    vals[2].type = "loo";
    vals[3].type = "koo";
    vals[4].type = "moo";
    /*elements_t elems = { space::half };*/
    reachability::operator<<(cout, vals);
    return 0;
}
```

However I get an error that no instance of the overloaded operator matches the argument list.

I have the same problem if I change the template of the operator to:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Container (&container)[])
```

I only managed to get it to work by doing:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Container (&container))
```

Comment: `result += std::string(elem) + ",";` why not use the stream operator directly ?

Comment: @UmNyobe because :
result.substr(0, result.length() - 1)
can I do this with the stream operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get compile-time error at declaration of your function, not when the body of that function template is being instantiated, you make SFINAE by adding another template parameter whose syntax is checked and if it doesn't make any sense, compiler will tell you about it by saying *no matching function for call ...*:

```
template <
  typename Container, 
  std::enable_if_t< is_container<Container>::value | 
                    std::is_array_v<Container> >* = nullptr>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Container&container ) {
```

as you can see, second template parameter was added, it will be `void* = nullptr` (which is valid syntax) only if `Container` is some class type which supports `begin`/`end`/`size` etc or it is built-in array type (`T []`). Otherwise, compiler complains that it cannot get `type` for declaration `type* = nullptr`.

---

```
std::vector<reachability::values_t> v;
std::list<reachability::values_t> l;
std::pair<int,int> p;
reachability::operator<<(cout, vals); // OK
reachability::operator<<(cout, v); // OK
reachability::operator<<(cout, l); // OK
reachability::operator<<(cout, p); // Wrong, compile-time error, no match ...
```

---

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/u_NA4a)

Comment: that's very helpful but what if I wanted to then do, instead of reachability::operator<<

cout << vals;
cout << "foo";

and to have the correct overload be used? Currently, in Visual Studio, when I try to run this, I get " 'operator <<' is ambiguous". So basically, can I add to my rules to not allow a string? Since it is an array of characters.

Comment: I guess the better question would be, can I somehow add to the rule that the container must have elements of type values_t only?

Comment: @Bbit Check [this link](https://godbolt.org/z/3RJwvy). `(is_container<Container>::value && 
         std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<Container>()[0])>,values_t>)` by `declval`, you create reference to `Container`, than `[]` is invoked, its type is got, and it is checked for equality with `values_t`. You have to use decay to discard referenceness returned by `operator[]`.

Comment: @Bbit You could also add this constraint to your `is_container` trait.

Comment: I may be missing something, if I run your code on that link with this in main:
    reachability::operator<<(cout, "p");
An error comes in the foreach of the custom operator complaining that the elem tried to convert from char to values_t and failed. 

    <source>:52:9: error: conversion from 'const char' to non-scalar type 'reachability::values_t' requested  52 |         for (values_t elem : container) {

Specifically though, with your solution, wouldn't 

cout << vals
cout << "p"

also work? It currently does not complaining of ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your defined `is_container`, use

```
template<
typename Container, 
std::enable_if_t<is_container<Container>::value, int>= 0>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Container &container) {}
```

[enable_if_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) will hide the function from overload resolution based on the boolean `is_container<Container>::value`. 
Note that your definition of `is_container` will accept a collection

```
std::vector<reachability::values_t> vals(5);
```

but not an array

```
reachability::values_t vals[5];
```

Comment: thanks very much. Your explanation helped me better understand the concept. As per the instructions of @rafix07 :

std::enable_if_t< is_container<Container>::value |
        std::is_array_v<Container> >* = nullptr>

would work arrays also work, however I was wondering, could you suggest what the rule should look like (so a similar is_container) for a container of containers ?

Comment: one way to do it is to add (not remplace) a new clause to partially enable : 

`std::enable_if_t< is_container<typename Container::value_type>::value>* = nullptr`

We literally check that the value type is also a container.